# android map refresh button/menu option?

Tags: android, google-maps

May I know how to implement button or menu option to get immediate update of user location on mapview, something like refresh button? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You may implement android.location.LocationListener interface
This will keep track of the User's Current Location.

On a click of mouse you may invoke last location from this Listener.

LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1l,100,locationListener);