# Android - Refresh GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps

I know this question would possibly duplicate, but I haven't found any solution which will solve my problem.

I am developing an app, in that I have inserted 10 pins using random function and also calculated their distance from current location and I have to select distance from `spinner` and according to that `googlemap` should be refreshed and will have to show only pins which comes under the distance.

I haven't found the proper solution which solves my purpose..Please help..

I found,

[How to force a location update after clicking on a Refresh menu button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228125/how-to-force-a-location-update-after-clicking-on-a-refresh-menu-button)

[android map refresh button/menu option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598699/android-map-refresh-button-menu-option)

Comment: you can easily set the map to new latitude/longitude, and then implement `map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener()`.

Comment: can u pls elaborate?? I want to select distance from spinner then will click ok..means functionality is to be on Button's OnclickListener

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10109796/826657

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple solution on this..

That is, when I click on button run the line `map.clear();` and in the `for_loop` according to `Latitude` and `Longitude` run the command as `marker.addmarker`

So that it will display only that marker which are in the distance range and will remove all the other markers.. :)